# Calling from Javascript to iOS Webview delegate is not triggeing

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, metaio

I have got Logic.js file from Metaio 3rd party sdk in my iOS Augmented reality based iOS project. This .JS file is created by Metaio creator.

I am modifying this file to call my iOS native web view. Basically, i want to call iOS native view from this .JS file.

Below is the Logic.js file used in the iOS project. Using `window.location` i'm trying to call UIWebview delegate from this .JS file.

```
var methodExists = function (object, method) {
    return typeof object !== 'undefined' && typeof method === 'function';
};

arel.sceneReady(function() {

    var scenario = {};
    scenario.objectName = "scenario";
    scenario.contents = []; // Array of all contents in this AR scenario
    scenario.trackables = []; // Array of all trackables in this AR scenario
    scenario.scenes = []; // Array of all scenes in this AR scenario
    scenario.googleAnalytics = null;
    scenario.currentScene = null;
    scenario.currentExperience360 = null;
    scenario.instantTrackingMode = false; // True if instant tracking is currently running
    scenario.currentTrackingConfigPathOrIdentifier = "html/resources/TrackingData.zip";

    scenario.addObject = function (object) {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.addObject(" + object.objectName + ")");
        this.registerObject(object);
        arel.Scene.addObject(object);
    };

    scenario.registerObject = function (object) {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.registerObject(" + object.objectName + ")");
        arel.Events.setListener(object, this.objectEventsCallback, scenario);
    };

    scenario.groupID = 0;
    scenario.getNewGroupID = function () {
        this.groupID++;
        return this.groupID;
    };

    scenario.getTrackable = function (identifier) {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.getTrackable(" + identifier + ")");
        var i;
        var trackable = null;
        if (!identifier || identifier === "") {
            arel.Debug.log("scenario.getTrackable(): Warning - identifier is empty, returning null");
            return trackable;
        }
        var allTrackables = this.trackables;
        for (i = 0; i < allTrackables.length; ++i) {
            trackable = allTrackables[i];
            if (trackable.objectName == identifier) {
                return trackable;
            }
            if (trackable.cosName == identifier) {
                return trackable;
            }
            if (trackable.cosID == identifier) {
                return trackable;
            }
        }
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.getTrackable(" + identifier + "): Error - could not correlate the given identifier to any known trackable.");
        return null;
    };

    scenario.sceneCallback = function (type, result) {
        if (!type) {
            return;
        }
        switch (type) {
        case arel.Events.Scene.ONTRACKING:
            this.onTrackingChanged(result);
            break;
        case arel.Events.Scene.ONVISUALSEARCHRESULT:
            break;
        case arel.Events.Scene.ONREADY:
            break;
        case arel.Events.Scene.ONLOAD:
        case arel.Events.Scene.ONLOCATIONUPDATE:
        default:
            break;
        }
    };

    scenario.objectEventsCallback = function (object, type, params) {
        switch (type) {
        case arel.Events.Object.ONREADY:
            if (methodExists(object, object.onLoaded)) {
                object.onLoaded();
            }
            break;
        case arel.Events.Object.ONTOUCHSTARTED:
            if (this.googleAnalytics) {
                this.googleAnalytics.logUIInteraction(arel.Plugin.Analytics.Action.TOUCHSTARTED, object.getID());
            }
            break;
        case arel.Events.Object.ONTOUCHENDED:
            if (this.googleAnalytics) {
                this.googleAnalytics.logUIInteraction(arel.Plugin.Analytics.Action.TOUCHENDED, object.getID());
            }
            break;
        case arel.Events.Object.ONINVISIBLE:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONVISIBLE:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONANIMATIONENDED:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONMOVIEENDED:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONLOAD:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONROTATED:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONSCALED:
        case arel.Events.Object.ONTRANSLATED:
        default:
            break;
        }
    };

    scenario.onTrackingChanged = function (trackingValuesList) {
        if (trackingValuesList.length === 0) {
            arel.Debug.log("scenario.onTrackingChanged: Error - list of tracking values is empty, this should be impossible.");
            return;
        }
        var i, trackingValues, cosName, cosID, trackable, trackingMethod, gaTrackingMethod;
        for (i = 0; i < trackingValuesList.length; i++) {
            trackingValues = trackingValuesList[i];
            trackable = null;
            cosName = trackingValues.getCoordinateSystemName();
            cosID = trackingValues.getCoordinateSystemID();
            // Try to find the trackable by its COS name first. If that fails, try the COS ID.
            if (cosName && cosName !== "") {
                trackable = this.getTrackable(cosName);
            }
            if (trackable === null && cosID) {
                trackable = this.getTrackable(cosID);
            }
            if (trackable === null) {
                arel.Debug.log("onTrackingChanged: Error - Can't find a trackable matching COS name '" + cosName + "' or COS ID '" + cosID + "'");
                return;
            }
            else {
                // The cosID 1 is strictly reserved for the 360 experience if it is running.
                if (scenario.currentExperience360 && cosID === 1) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            switch (trackingValues.getState()) {
            case arel.Tracking.STATE_NOTTRACKING:
                arel.Debug.log("onTrackingChanged: " + trackable.objectName + " is not tracking");
                if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onTrackingLost)) {
                    trackable.onTrackingLost(trackingValues);
                }
                break;
            case arel.Tracking.STATE_TRACKING:
                arel.Debug.log("onTrackingChanged: " + trackable.objectName + " is tracking");
                if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onDetected)) {
                    trackable.onDetected();
                }
                if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onTracked)) {
                    trackable.onTracked(trackingValues);
                }
                if (this.googleAnalytics) {
                    trackingMethod  = trackingValues.getType();
                    gaTrackingMethod = this.googleAnalytics.trackingTypeToAnalyticsType(trackingMethod);
                    this.googleAnalytics.logTrackingEvent(gaTrackingMethod, arel.Plugin.Analytics.Action.STATE_TRACKING, cosID, cosName);
                }
                break;
            case arel.Tracking.STATE_EXTRAPOLATED:
            case arel.Tracking.STATE_INITIALIZED:
            case arel.Tracking.STATE_REGISTERED:
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };


    scenario.startInstantTracking = function () {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.startInstantTracking()");
        if (this.instantTrackingMode) {
            return;
        }
        this.instantTrackingMode = true;

           if (scenario.currentExperience360) {
            scenario.currentExperience360.hide();
        }

        // Iterate over all trackables, simulate an onTrackingLost() for all those which are currently tracking.
        var i, trackable;
        for (i = 0; i < this.trackables.length; ++i) {
            trackable = this.trackables[i];
            if (trackable.isCurrentlyTracking && trackable != userDevice) {
                if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onTrackingLost)) {
                    trackable.onTrackingLost();
                }
            }
        }
        arel.Scene.startInstantTracking(arel.Tracking.INSTANT2D);
        if (methodExists(this, this.onStartInstantTracking)) {
            this.onStartInstantTracking();
        }
    };

    scenario.stopInstantTracking = function () {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.stopInstantTracking()");
        if (!this.instantTrackingMode) {
            return;
        }
        this.instantTrackingMode = false;
        if (methodExists(instantTracker, instantTracker.onTrackingLost)) {
            instantTracker.onTrackingLost();
        }
        this.setTrackingConfiguration(this.currentTrackingConfigPathOrIdentifier);
        if (methodExists(this, this.onStopInstantTracking)) {
            this.onStopInstantTracking();
        }
    };

    scenario.skipTrackingInitialization = function () {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.skipTrackingInitialization()");
        arel.Scene.sensorCommand("initialize", "", function(a) {});
        if (methodExists(this, this.onSkipTrackingInitialization)) {
            this.onSkipTrackingInitialization();
        }
    };

    scenario.reloadTrackingConfiguration = function () {
        arel.Debug.log("scenario.reloadTrackingConfiguration()");
        this.setTrackingConfiguration(this.currentTrackingConfigPathOrIdentifier);
        if (methodExists(this, this.onReloadTrackingConfiguration)) {
            this.onReloadTrackingConfiguration();
        }
    };

    scenario.setTrackingConfiguration = function (trackingConfigPathOrIdentifier) {
        // Iterate over all trackables, simulate an onTrackingLost() for all those which are currently tracking.
        var i, trackable;
        for (i = 0; i < this.trackables.length; ++i) {
            trackable = this.trackables[i];
            if (trackable.isCurrentlyTracking && trackable != userDevice) {
                if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onTrackingLost)) {
                    trackable.onTrackingLost();
                }
            }
        }

        // Set the new tracking configuration.
        arel.Scene.setTrackingConfiguration(trackingConfigPathOrIdentifier);
    };

    scenario.onStartup = function () {
        arel.Debug.log("Welcome to the 'HouseProject' Augmented Reality experience.");

        arel.Events.setListener(arel.Scene, scenario.sceneCallback, scenario);

        if (google_analytics_id) {
            arel.Debug.log("Google Analytics is enabled. Your account ID is: " + google_analytics_id);
            arel.Debug.log("The event sampling rate is: arel.Plugin.Analytics.EventSampling.ONCE");
            scenario.googleAnalytics = new arel.Plugin.Analytics(google_analytics_id, arel.Plugin.Analytics.EventSampling.ONCE, "");
        } else {
            arel.Debug.log("Note: No Google Analytics ID is set - Google Analytics will be disabled.");
        }

        if (methodExists(scenario, scenario.onLoaded)) {
            scenario.onLoaded();
        }

        // The following contents have been defined in the index.xml file, therefore we need to register them
        // and call their onLoaded() event manually.
        scenario.registerObject(model6);
        if (methodExists(model6, model6.onLoaded)) {
            model6.onLoaded();
        }
        scenario.registerObject(model7);
        if (methodExists(model7, model7.onLoaded)) {
            model7.onLoaded();
        }


        if (methodExists(userDevice, userDevice.onLoaded)) {
            userDevice.onLoaded();
        }

        // All objects have been defined, so start the AR experience by calling each trackable's .onLoaded() method.
        var i, trackable;
        for (i = 0; i < scenario.trackables.length; ++i) {
            trackable = scenario.trackables[i];
            if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onLoaded)) {
                trackable.onLoaded();
            }
        }

        // Call the first scene's display() once to make sure that the content of that scene is initially visible.
        scene1.display();
    };


    var scene1 = {};
    scenario.scenes.push(scene1);
    scene1.objectName = "scene1";

    scene1.display = function () {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".display()");

        if (scenario.currentScene == this) {
            return;
        }

        // Iterate over all trackables, simulate an onTrackingLost() for all those which are currently tracking.
        var trackingTrackables = [];
        var i, trackable;
        for (i = 0; i < scenario.trackables.length; ++i) {
            trackable = scenario.trackables[i];
            if (trackable.isCurrentlyTracking) {
                // The instant tracker should be excluded from the tracking ones because it will be stopped later on.
                if (trackable !== instantTracker) {
                    trackingTrackables.push(trackable);
                }
                if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onTrackingLost)) {
                    trackable.onTrackingLost();
                }
            }
        }

        // In case any instant tracking is currently running, stop it before switching to the other scene.
        scenario.stopInstantTracking();

        var previousExperience360 = null;
        if (scenario.currentExperience360) {
            previousExperience360 = scenario.currentExperience360;
            scenario.currentExperience360.hide();
        }

        scenario.currentScene = this;

        // Iterate over all tracking trackables again, this time simulating an onDetected() and onTracked() event
        // for all those which are currently tracking.
        for (i = 0; i < trackingTrackables.length; ++i) {
            trackable = trackingTrackables[i];
            if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onDetected)) {
                trackable.onDetected();
            }
            if (methodExists(trackable, trackable.onTracked)) {
                trackable.onTracked(trackable.currentTrackingValues);
            }
        }

        if (previousExperience360) {
            // A 360 was displayed in the previous scene, we now need to check whether any 360 in the new scene
            // is triggered by the same trackable. If so, that 360 should be displayed.
            var i, content;
            for (i = 0; i < scenario.contents.length; ++i) {
                content = scenario.contents[i];
                if (content.type == "Experience360" && content.scene == this && 
                    content.associatedTrackable == previousExperience360.associatedTrackable) {
                    content.display();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (methodExists(this, this.onDisplayed)) {
            this.onDisplayed();
        }
    };


    var instantTracker = {};
    scenario.trackables.push(instantTracker);
    instantTracker.objectName = "instantTracker";
    instantTracker.cosName = "InstantTracker";
    instantTracker.cosID = "1";
    instantTracker.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
    instantTracker.currentTrackingValues = null;
    instantTracker.onTracked = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTracked()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = true;
        this.currentTrackingValues = trackingValues;
    };

    instantTracker.onTrackingLost = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTrackingLost()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
        this.currentTrackingValues = null;
    };


    var pattern2 = {};
    scenario.trackables.push(pattern2);
    pattern2.objectName = "pattern2";
    pattern2.cosName = "Home1_1";
    pattern2.cosID = "1";
    pattern2.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
    pattern2.currentTrackingValues = null;
    pattern2.onTracked = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTracked()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = true;
        this.currentTrackingValues = trackingValues;
                // Try to call native from here

      window.location = "js-call:" + "myObjectiveCFunction";

        model6.display();
        model6.play("Default Take", false);

    };

    pattern2.onTrackingLost = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTrackingLost()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
        this.currentTrackingValues = null;
        model6.hide();
    };


    var pattern3 = {};
    scenario.trackables.push(pattern3);
    pattern3.objectName = "pattern3";
    pattern3.cosName = "Home2_2";
    pattern3.cosID = "2";
    pattern3.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
    pattern3.currentTrackingValues = null;
    pattern3.onTracked = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTracked()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = true;
        this.currentTrackingValues = trackingValues;
        model7.display();
        model7.play("Default Take", false);
    };

    pattern3.onTrackingLost = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTrackingLost()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
        this.currentTrackingValues = null;
        model7.hide();
    };


    var userDevice = {};
    userDevice.isCurrentlyTracking = true; // The pose of the user's device is always tracked...
    scenario.trackables.push(userDevice);
    userDevice.objectName = "userDevice";
    userDevice.cosName = "Device";
    userDevice.cosID = "-1";
    userDevice.onTracked = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTracked()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = true;
        this.currentTrackingValues = trackingValues;
    };

    userDevice.onTrackingLost = function (trackingValues) {
        arel.Debug.log(this.objectName + ".onTrackingLost()");
        this.isCurrentlyTracking = false;
        this.currentTrackingValues = null;
    };

    // Kick-off the AR experience by calling the scenario's onStartup() method as soon as AREL is ready
    scenario.onStartup();
});
```

On the iOS Side: UIWebview placed in a view controller and its delegate method to get Javascript call.

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2
    shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

        NSLog(@"Inside WebView");

NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

        if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-call:"]) {

            NSLog(@"Call from Javascript");
            return NO;
        }

        // Accept this location change
        return YES;

    }
```

Here is the webview object created in header file:

```
#import "MetaioSDKViewController.h"
#import <metaioSDK/GestureHandlerIOS.h>
#import <metaioSDK/IARELInterpreterIOS.h>

// forward declarations
@class EAGLView;

@interface ARELViewController : MetaioSDKViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, IARELInterpreterIOSDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    metaio::IARELInterpreterIOS*    m_ArelInterpreter;
    GestureHandlerIOS*              m_pGestureHandlerIOS;
    NSString*                       m_arelFile;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* m_arelWebView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil instructions:(NSString *)arelTutorialConfig;

- (void) onSDKReady;

@end
```

And in .mm its set: (NOTE: Interface Builder also Delegate has been set )

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    m_arelWebView.delegate = self;

}
```

This is not at all getting called from Javascript when this functionality is executing.

Could someone advise me what could be the cause? Why the Javascript call is not triggering this native webview delegate.

Thank you!

Comment: R u sure that the  window.location = "js-call:" + "myObjectiveCFunction"; is really invoke? Can u pop alert right before this relocation?

Comment: R u sure that u did your UIWebView's delegate to be the right Object?

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are creating the UIWebView object ?

Comment: @ Brams, I updated the code as you asked. Its showing error in Xcode console as "The URL can’t be shown, (null)".

Comment: @gran33, Its showing alert in JS file at that time of scanning the image from Metaio. But, on the Xcode console log, its showing error as "The URL can’t be shown, (null)"

Comment: I have another doubt, "window.location" works only if iOS webview loaded the custom javascript file? In this Metaio, JS file loaded from one index.html file. JS doesn't directly loaded by iOS native webview. May be that's why its NOT invoking the iOS webview delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem,
I presume you have used Native Bridge library: https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge.

That library makes you implement

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request      navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

method but in MetaioCloudPluginViewController (superclass of ARELViewController) u can see that u need to implement:

```
/** Overwrite this method if you want to be able to handle custom URL schemes that are launched
 * from your channel
 * \param request the request that is being sent
 *
 * You can use it like this:
 * NSURL* theURL = [request mainDocumentURL];
 * NSString* absoluteString = [theURL absoluteString];
 * if( [[absoluteString lowercaseString] hasPrefix:@"yourapp://"] )
 * {
 *   // do something
 *   return NO;
 * }
 * return YES;
 */
- (BOOL) shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request;
```

u just need to use that

Answer (score 0):

I think the default webview delegate calls are broken in the last version. What works however is:

In the javascript file (at the location of your choosing):

```
arel.Media.openWebsite("appname://actionID");
```

In iOS:

```
-(bool)openWebsiteWithUrl:(NSString *)url inExternalApp:(bool)openInExternalApp
{    
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
    if([url rangeOfString:@"actionID"].location != NSNotFound) {
        //Got it! I can communicate with my Javascript, hooray!
    }
}
```